# Tagging video with the app/developer_id used to upload the video

Tags: facebook, video, tags

Does Facebook provides any way to associate the application [that is used to upload the video] with the video?

Answer (score 0):

It'll automatically be logged as such on Facebook's side, and there's a 'via ' link appended to the video display page on Facebook.com

If you're asking about anything else you'll need to be more specific.